# can anyone please tell me why given below 's snippet output is coming undefined?, was expecting test

Tags: javascript

Given below is the snippet that  did not get why undefined output is coming, please elaborate
Thanks in advance.

```
var name = "test";

function message() {
console.log(name);
 var name = "test 2";
}

message()
```

Comment: `var name` inside the function makes `name` a local variable for the whole function, shadowing the global variable `name`. The variable starts off `undefined` until it is defined (`name = "test 2"` is not hoisted).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because you declared a local variable with the same name, and it masks the global variable.

So when you write `name` you refer to the local variable.

That's true even if you write it before the declaration of that local variable, variables in JavaScript are function-scoped.

However, you can use the fact that global variables are properties of the global object (`window`):

```js
var name = "test";

function message1() {
  console.log(name);
  var name = "test 2";
}

function message2() {
  console.log(name);
}

function message3() {
  console.log(name);
  name = "test 2";
}

function message4() {
  console.log(name);
  var name = window.name || "";
}

function message5() {
  var name = window.name || "";
  console.log(name);
}

message1(); // undefined
message2(); // test
message3(); // test
message4(); // undefined
message5(); // test 2
```